# unable to remove login ip range using mdapi with simple_salesforce

Tags: simple-salesforce, mdapi

I am able to get the profile login range ip, set it to what I want but when I try to update the profile I get many error messages.

```
sf = Salesforce(username='test-30djtctsyq5a@example.com', password='1234#e', security_token='12345Idp6TrsKbmb', client_id='My App', domain='test')
mdapi = sf.mdapi
admin_profile = mdapi.Profile.read("Admin")
print(admin_profile["loginIpRanges"][0]["startAddress"]) # 0.0.0.0
admin_profile["loginIpRanges"][0]["startAddress"] = "1.1.1.1"
logger.error(mdapi.Profile.update(admin_profile)) # here I get the error below
```

> "You can't edit tab settings for WorkUpgradeUser, as it's not a valid
> tab.), (FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can't edit tab settings for
> WorkerCompCoverageClass, as it's not a valid tab.),
> (FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can't edit tab settings for
> WorkforceCapacityPlan, as it's not a valid tab.),
> (FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can't edit tab settings for
> WorkforceEngagementManagementSettings, as it's not a valid tab.),
> (FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can't edit tab settings for
> WstDispoEmssnFctrSet, as it's not a valid tab.),
> (FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can't edit tab settings for
> WstDispoEmssnFctrSetItm, as it's not a valid tab.),
> (FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can't edit tab settings for mailapp,
> as it's not a valid tab.), "

my ultimate goal is actually to remove the login ip ranges completely, but if not I would settle for just creating a new entry from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

when trying to remove all the ip ranges like this:

```
admin_profile["loginIpRanges"] = []
```

I got the same error as above.